# How does Vagrant automatically install Docker on CentOS?

Tags: centos, vagrant, docker

I wonder how Vagrant is installing Docker with the Docker provisioner. Is Vagrant using packages from some package-manager or is it built from source? Which commands were fired to finish the installation process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found it by myself. Here's the [sourcecode](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/tree/abb9e5478a3b0a645fb369ecf80a9a38ee29edd2/plugins/provisioners/docker/cap/redhat).

Vagrant is using yum on CentOS.
For CentOS 6 Vagrant uses the package ´docker-io´ in EPEL and for CentOS 7 ´docker´ in the Extras Repo.

Answer (score 0):

1: if you must use centos . you must update you centos python version => 7.0 
2: if you don't . pls use coreos . coreos begin with docker :)

if you want to get commond line for install docker-io .

add commonet

Comment: Actually I can install docker-io successfully. The problem is that I want to create a golden image with centos 6.6 and docker 1.3.1. Everything works as expected when I let Vagrant install docker. But if I want to package it into the golden image it's somehow broken. Thus inside of a container in docker I can't connect to yum (it can't connect to the yum base-mirror). So the idea was that Vagrant is doing something special.